# Node.js app exponentially growing latency for http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, axios

I have an Express application with one endpoint, it takes a string from request, sends a request with this string to a different server and returns response. It's able to handle some load pretty well, but once I start cranking it up latency starts growing uncontrollably and ruins entire application. Below you can find sample graph, first I try to go with 60k requests per minute, then I do just about 5k and it's perfectly smooth both in throughput and latency.

I tried using both built in `https` module and `axios` library, both give exact same results.

Is there some setting I'm missing? Like max concurrent requests or something like that. I'm not too experienced with Node, so a bit confused by what I'm seeing, especially since it's reproduced on completely different infrastructures and at the same time a Java application on same infrastructures is able to do about 100k a minute without any issues.

Here's sample code that I use to send requests:

```
export const callService = axios => async request => {
  const params = {
    address: request.fullAddress
  }
  const response = await axios.get('endpoint', {
    params
  })
  return {
    result: response.data
  }
}
```

Here's how I get an instance of axios, which I later pass to the currying function above:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: SERVICE_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
})
```

I did verify that once I remove this call and just mock the response, I can go with much larger numbers with no latency issues.

[image: Performance graph]

### Update

Did additional testing today with this simple piece of code, no `Express` server at all, just this code. When I use `Array(1000)` (effectively setting concurrent request count to `1000`) it works ok and takes just a couple of seconds to complete the entire operation. But if I try setting it to `10000`, then I start seeing these issues again. Might be worth mentioning that I am doing that on a Mac with Catalina, however, same behavior is observed when app runs in PCF. Code:

```
const axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL: SERVICE_URL,
  httpAgent: new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
  })
})
const params = {
  // some query params
}
console.log(Date.now())
Promise.all([...Array(1000).keys()]
  .map(() => axiosInstance.get('path', {
    params
  })))
  .then(it => {
    console.log(Date.now())
  })
```

### Update 2

It looks like the problem might be related to DNS lookup. I noticed that when I execute large number of requests, it gets stuck for some time before failing one of the requests with `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` and then all others fail with timeout. Not sure how to fix that though

### Update 3

Setting higher `ulimit` seems to help with the previous issue, but with high number of requests all of them start timing out.

Comment: Is this axios instance created for every request or do you keep a reference to it in your controller and just pass it down to `callService`?

Comment: @eol just one instance

Comment: @eol ok just tried creating a new instance for every request and it completely cured the issue. Any ideas what the root cause of the problem was?

Comment: Can't tell you what the root cause was, maybe some issue with the underlying socket when only one instance is used. But I'm glad you found a solution :)

Comment: @eol looks like I spoke too soon. It seemed that it helped, but turned out I made a silly mistake in the code that eliminated requests. So the issue is still the same even with unique instance per request and `httpsAgent: null`

Comment: @LeonidBor the DNS failures look like a symptom of your system running out of available file descriptors. That might be due to incoming or outgoing requests; each outbound API call is going to open up a socket to the remote server (and the default file descriptor limit is usually 1000); or, your server might be holding too many connections open from the incoming requests. Either way, you can try bumping it up (`sudo ulimit -n 12288` perhaps -- you may need to take extra steps depending on your OS).

Comment: @RobertNubel when i call `ulimit` in terminal it prints `unlimited`

Comment: @LeonidBor I'm no expert on ulimit, but I think that's the system-level hard limit. Check `ulimit -n` as that, I believe, is the actual file descriptor limit that will be enforced for user-level processes.

Comment: @RobertNubel thank you for your suggestions! `ulimit -n` indeed returned just 256, however, setting it to higher values did not help with timeout issue. Pretty much now when I go beyond some uncertain number all requests start timing out. Seems like when I approach 3000 concurrent requests I get something between 0 to 150 requests that time out

Comment: You could try switching to superagent, which benchmarks faster than axios for node apps, but that doesn't really explain the timeouts (which are generally a symptom of a connection being dropped/blackholed). Can you run that Java app you mentioned locally to rule out any external networking issues? Also, it doesn't look like Axios can set a connection timeout (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1739) which is a bummer as a low value there would help your process avoid lengthy connection timeouts.

Comment: @RobertNubel looks like setting `ulimit` solved the problem after all, now the timeouts were caused by Elastic APM agent that I was using. Once I removed it the throughput went up big. Thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit here looks to be your system running out of available file descriptors (the sporadic DNS lookup failures are a common symptom of this). Since you've ruled out Express being related, I suspect this is due to the concurrent outbound requests being made: each outbound API call is going to open up a socket to the remote server (and the default file descriptor limit is usually 1000).

The fix depends on your exact OS, but on a typical Unix system, you can check your available file descriptors for user processes with:

```
ulimit -n
```

And raise it with something like this (or search StackOverflow for "raise file descriptor limit"):

```
sudo ulimit -n 10000
```

Note: There were other factors at work here, as noted in the comment chain on the original question, and many different issues can affect a system's throughput: memory pressure, CPU throttling, poor-quality HTTP libraries, etc.